# Exponential function algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, graphics

I need to implement a function that interpolates an exponential curve from three points, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have a graph that has the Y axis as percentage, 0 to 100% and X as 0 to 10.

The only points that I know are (50,7), (100,10) and (0,0).

I know I can create an array that has the percentages and values and loop through it, but this does not feel like the "right" way to do it.  Is there a more direct algorithm?

Comment: there is already a mistake. when X goes from 0 to 10, you can't have a point (50,7), because usually points are given as (X, Y).

Comment: Do you mean "exponential?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the **formula** :

```
partial : total = % : 100
partial (the value) = (total * %) / 100
```

---

**Code**

```
<?php

$points = array("8%,67%","36%,74%","73%,13%");


function return_value($percentage,$total) {
    $value = ($total * $percentage) / 100.0;
    return $value;
}

function evaluate_points($points) {
    $max_x = 100.0; // As float value
    $max_y = 10.0; // As float value
    for ($point = 0; $point < count($points); $point++) {
        //Replace the % sign
        $points[$point] = str_replace("%", "", $points[$point]);

        $point_percentages = explode(",", $points[$point]);
        $x_percentage = $point_percentages[0];
        $y_percentage = $point_percentages[1];
        echo("The value for x is : ".return_value($x_percentage,$max_x) ."<br>");
        echo("The value for y is : ".return_value($y_percentage,$max_y). "<br><br>");
    }
}

evaluate_points($points);


?>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For now I am trying to understand it the most as I can :)  I think il manage to convert it to php this time,  If I realy stuck at some point il recomment and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: Allright :) Last thing: if this helped you, would you mark this answer as correct so that even other users can see it ? Thanks a lot. Ask for anything

Comment: But wait, did you need something to get the percentage from a given value ?

Comment: yes this is what im trying to acheive :)  Giving the percentage % and get the value from it.

Comment: My bad ! Give me 5 minutes I will provide all the code you need

Comment: Done :) Look at the second part of the answer

Comment: I don't understand. I think we are misunderstanding eachother. What im trying to do is basicly getting a value by giving a percentage. I do not have both cordinate normaly. The only value I normaly have is either x or y and not both.   I still thanks you for your time and help.

Comment: Don't worry, I'am here to help you. As far as I understood, you need to convert a % to a value right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61444/discussion-between-nicolas-racine-and-foxnos).